# Analogue of Fáry's theorem taking sphere and geodesics instead of plane and straight lines.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Fary's theorem states that any simple planar graph can be drawn without crossings so that its edges are straight line segments (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem)). The proof is based on the [Art gallery theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem#Chv.C3.A1tal.27s_art_gallery_theorem), so I would have asked also this latter. But, perhaps there is a simpler answer on my question.

In any case, my question is the following.

Is it true, that any simple planar graph can be drawn on the sphere without crossings so that its edges are geodesic segments?

Comment: I suspect it's true, and even better than $\Bbb R^2$: I bet we can draw all planar loop-free *multigraphs* on the sphere with geodesic edges!

Comment: I guess it's true.  Couldn't you draw any graph on the sphere by first drawing it on the plane, then copying the drawing to a very small part of the sphere where the great circle segments are very close to straight lines in the original drawing?

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus: Yes, this is convincing, thanks!