# Has Fáry's theorem been proved/documented/given an exposition for embeddings into the 2-sphere?

Tags: reference-request, spheres, planar-graphs, riemann-sphere

This question is partly to breath new life into [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246121/analogue-of-f%c3%a1rys-theorem-taking-sphere-and-geodesics-instead-of-plane-and-stra), which is essentially equivalent to the present one, partly to find a quotable reference quickly, since I am working on an exposition related to this:

**Question.**

Is there an exposition in the literature of Fáry's theorem on straight-line-embeddings of planar graphs, but for the 2-sphere instead of the plane, and with geodesic/great-circle-segments instead of straight-line-segments?

**Remark.**

- I am aware that a sketch of an argument transferring Fáry's theorem from the plane to the sphere has been given in [the above question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246121/analogue-of-f%c3%a1rys-theorem-taking-sphere-and-geodesics-instead-of-plane-and-stra); this is more of a reference-request, with an eye towards existing expositions in the published literature.